# Is there any way to open link in anew tab from inner html (angular 6)

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

I have a span tag with inner html like this

In my html :

```
<span [innerHTML]="description"></span>
```

and in my ts:

```
description = "some random text  https://stackoverflow.com/ Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
```

[image: displaying it like this]

It displays the link but when I click on that link it is opening in the same tab but I want it be opened in a new tab.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case that you are using innerHtml property binding you can place a [html link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) in your description text with [target="_blank"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) to open the link in a new tab:

```
description =
    'some random text <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">https://stackoverflow.com/</a> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s';
```